# Powershell [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile] can't ignore "System Volume Information' folder

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a automation to zip a entire drive into a zip file.

and I come up with the following code:

```
$toZipDirectory = 'F:\'

$zipFilePath = 'E:\Backup.zip'

[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($toZipDirectory, $zipFilePath)
```

This code works fine when I tested it targeting one especific folder under my F: drive but when I added the source as the root of F: I got the following error:

```
Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 'F:\System Volume Information' is denied."
```

Is there any way to workaround this? I don't need this folder since it's a "Windows thing".

Comment: As the function name implies, `CreateFromDirectory` can take a directory as source, not a drive. P.S. why try to zip an entire drive in the first place? There's lots of free disk imaging software around.

Comment: Well... putting together some brains cells here what you sad make totally sense... ```CreateFromDirectory``` don't take a drive.
Since this is to happen in a company environment I need to work with the tools that I have and unfortunately a disk image software is not amoung of it...

Comment: Why not use the Windows server backup tool?